# Can I use production certificate and distribution profile without goping for development .cer and profiles

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can I use production certificate and distribution profile without goping for development .cer and profiles, as i am running out of time.

Any help is appreciated ?? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with goping

Comment: Explain your issue with more details, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use production certificate and distribution provisioning profile to submit your app to the App Store.
You cannot run application using distribution profile because apple not gives option to add device.

1. If your are making development provisioning profile then
   developerSite will gives option to select developer certificate,
   there is not any option for distribution certificate.
2. If your are making distribution provisioning profile then
   developerSite will gives option to select distribution certificate,
   there is not any option for development certificate.

check screen shot.

[image]